# CodeIgniter validation issue on false condition?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) form validation library.

Example view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

            <h5>Username</h5>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

            <h5>Password</h5>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

            <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
            <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

            <h5>Email Address</h5>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Controller

```
<?php
    class Form extends CI_Controller {

        function index()
        {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('myform');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('formsuccess');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

In this case when I fill in username, password, confirm password and email leave blank and after submit form it's get an error of email required. It's fine, but in this case my username, password, confirm password field also data has been lost, so please help me in this case when any error occurred.

It should not clear other input fields...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have founded the solution:

We have to use set_value() in the value parameter like this:

```
<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>
```

Comment: You can use echoing error to know which field is not right populated. Check [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use it via an Ajax post. Don't need confusing whether.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="username" value=<?php echo $this->input->post("username");?> size="50" />
```

Comment: Although this might be a good answer, please consider adding some more explanation about why this is the right solution and what exactly you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your form code with this code:

```
<form>
    <h5>Username</h5>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php if (validation_errors()) { echo set_value('username'); } ?>" size = "50" />

    <h5>Password</h5>
    <input type = "text" name = "password" value = "<?php if (validation_errors()) { echo set_value('password'); } ?>" size = "50" />

    <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
    <input type = "text" name = "passconf" value = "<?php if (validation_errors()) { echo set_value('passconf'); } ?>" size = "50" />

    <h5>Email Address</h5>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" value = "<?php if (validation_errors()) {   echo set_value('email'); } ?>" size = "50" />

    <div><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

        <h5>Username</h5>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username');?>" size="50" />

        <h5>Password</h5>
        <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>" size="50" />

        <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
        <input type="text" name="passconf" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf');?>" size="50" />

        <h5>Email Address</h5>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" size="50" />

        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```